# getting the first string in object javascript lodash

Tags: javascript, string, reactjs, ecmascript-6, lodash

i have a data (array of object)

example data.

```
"data": [
{
"name": "name",
"mockupImages": "http://test.com/image1.png,http://test.com/image2.png"
}]
```

===========================================
here's my code snippets

```
<Row>
<Col xs={4}>
<img style={{ width: '40', height: '60'}} src={_.map(data, 'mockupImages')} />
</Col>
</Row
```

I already get the data mockupImages, the problem is I need to accept only one string

Comment: Do you want to show all images or just the 1st one?

Comment: I think what you want is to map all the 'mockupImages' into `col` If that is the case then use the function instead `_.map(array, function(){...})`. Then you can return a `img` with `src=mockupImages`.

Comment: just one only :)

Comment: Just for fun: with destructuring: `const [result] = (([{mockupImages:u}]) => u.split(','))(data);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the 1st string, you can use [`_.get()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#get):

```js
const data = [{"name":"name1","mockupImages":"http://test.com/image1.png"},{"name":"name2","mockupImages":"http://test.com/image2.png"}];

const result = _.get(_.get(_.map(data, 'mockupImages'), 0).split(','), 0);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I already try _.get(_.map(data, 'mockupImages'), 0) , but i need to get only 1 string,

Comment: You have 2 strings inside mockupImages - http://test.com/image1.png,http://test.com/image2.png. Add this info to your question.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Try to get the server to return something more sensible.